# perl module UUID-0.05 make failed in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gcc, makefile, uuid, perl-module

I am facing problems on installing perl module UUID-0.05.

> $ sudo make
>
> cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN
>   -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g   -DVERSION=\"0.05\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.05\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE"
>
> UUID.c UUID.xs:5:23: fatal error: uuid/uuid.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated. make: *** [UUID.o] Error 1

See my answer below.

Comment: I tried installing lot of packages but nothing helped. Finally the correct package required is                                           > sudo apt-get install uuid-dev

Comment: With `apt-file` you can find out which package contains which file: `apt-file search uuid/uuid.h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slaven Rezic,

You are right.

```
/usr/bin$ apt-file search uuid/uuid.h
libboost1.46-dev: /usr/include/boost/uuid/uuid.hpp
libboost1.46-doc: /usr/share/doc/libboost1.46-doc/HTML/libs/uuid/uuid.html
libboost1.48-dev: /usr/include/boost/uuid/uuid.hpp
libboost1.48-doc: /usr/share/doc/libboost1.48-doc/HTML/libs/uuid/uuid.html
uuid-dev: /usr/include/uuid/uuid.h
```

this works great. thanks for the info.